# How to define new exampleSetOutPut format?

Tags: java, rapidminer

When creating new operator, we create input port to receive data and output port for delivering data. For each input port we fix its data type like:

```
 exampleSetInput.addPrecondition (
     new ExampleSetPrecondition (
         exampleSetInput,
         Ontology.ATTRIBUTE_VALUE));
```

And also we define the ouput port data type like:

```
getTransformer().addPassThroughRule (
    exampleSetInput, exampleSetOutput);
```

This condition will generate the same output data type and format as the input. My question is how to define new output format and data type with no relation with the input. For example the input format have numerical data type and four attributes, I want the out put data to be of type String and with new two attributes.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I find the solution in the delivered document by rapid miner community "How to extend rapidminer". It consists on the use of the following function in the constructor when defining the ports rules:

```
getTransformer().addRule(new ExampleSetPassThroughRule(exampleSetInput, exampleSetOutPut,    SetRelation.SUBSET) {
        @Override
        public ExampleSetMetaData modifyExampleSet(ExampleSetMetaData metaData) throws UndefinedParameterError {
            metaData.removeAllAttributes();//This will remove all input attribtes
            metaData.addAttribute(new AttributeMetaData("item", Ontology.STRING));//here the creation of new attribute 

            return metaData;
        }
    });
```

Also you can modify input attributes names or types as you need.